# Change APN of GSM connection

Tags: linux, networking, networkmanager, gsm

I'm trying to change the APN of my GSM connection but don't know how to do it, googling didn't really help.
This is my current connection:

```
NAME               UUID                                  TYPE             DEVICE
Vodafone Default   7730a562-f660-4537-974f-defb7ceecee6  gsm              cdc-wdm0
```

It has an APN defined (obviously) but I don't know where I can modify it. I looked into the `/etc/ppp/` directory already but didn't find anything useful.
Also, is it possible to change this with the NetworkManager (e.g. creating a new connection with a new APN)? Because I tried creating a new connection (with `nmtui`) but didn't see a possibility to create a GSM connection, just wifi etc.

Otherwise, do you have an idea where I should look? Thanks for your help in advance!

Fabian

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to answer without really knowing the details of your setup. If you use PPPd you should be able to decide on the APN you want to use by using a symlink in /etc/ppp/chatscripts. If you use Ubuntu, you should be able to do the configuration with `nmcli` as written in [1](https://docs.ubuntu.com/core/en/stacks/network/network-manager/docs/configure-cellular-connections).

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer! Someone on here already suggested the `/etc/ppp/chatscripts` but I don't have this directory. I'll try to do it with nmcli.